# Multi Threading Creating Random delay per thread

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, multidimensional-array

I need help in solving this I need to have a random delay on each person I just don't know how to implement it in arrayed threads. somebody help me please !
I need something in linkedlist in threads maybe or whatever, I need to know where and how to implement. I'm stuck with this. im suppose to make an arrayed threads to make a delay for each person

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Try5 extends Thread {

    public static Semaphore Door = new Semaphore(3);
    public static int COUNTER = 0;
    public static final int LIST = 3;
    public static int VACANCY    = LIST;

    //private DELAY_GENERATOR[] Person;
    //private LinkedList<Runnable> taskQueue;



    public static void main (String[] args) {


         class CONTROLLER extends Thread{
            int ID;
            int SEX;
            public CONTROLLER(int a, int b){
                ID = a;
                SEX = b;
                }
            public void run(){
                while(VACANCY < 0){
                if(SEX == 0){
                    try{
                    Door.acquire();
                    VACANCY--;
                    this.MEN();
                    System.out.println("MEN has ENTERED The CR");
                    }catch (InterruptedException ex){}
                }
                else{
                    try{
                    Door.acquire();
                    VACANCY--;
                    this.WOMEN();
                    System.out.println("WOMEN has ENTERED The CR");
                    }catch (InterruptedException ex){}

                }}}

            public void MEN(){
                System.out.println("MEN has USED The CR");
                //taskQueue = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
                //Person = new DELAY_GENERATOR[COUNTER];
                //Person[COUNTER] = new DELAY_GENERATOR();
                //Person[COUNTER].start();
                //Queue<Integer> MenQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                //MenQueue.offer(COUNTER);
                VACANCY++;
                Door.release();
            }
            public void WOMEN(){
                System.out.println("WOMEN has USED The CR");
                //taskQueue = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
                //Person = new DELAY_GENERATOR[COUNTER];
                //Person[COUNTER] = new DELAY_GENERATOR();
                //Person[COUNTER].start();
                //Queue<Integer> WomenQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                //WomenQueue.offer(COUNTER);
                VACANCY++;
                Door.release();
            }


        }
        class DELAY_GENERATOR extends Thread{

            public void run(){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((int)Math.random()*(5000-1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                }
            }


            }

        }



    }
```

Comment: What logic you want to implement for delay ?

Comment: Why is it all in UPPER_CASE?  What is wrong with the random delay code you have now?

Comment: when  men or women entered the CR it should have a delay . I want to implement Threaded delay where it can have multiple thread but in arrays or linkedlist ...

Comment: @PeterLawrey i want to implement a threaded array , where I only need to declare a single line code to execute many threads. It's my habbit to put it in UPPER_CASE

Comment: @ProblematicSolution I suggest you follow Java code conventions. I also suggest not extending Thread directly as this tends to lead to strange issues. I do suggest using an ExecutorService esp for a pool of threads.

Answer (score 0):

This is a VERY simple producer/consumer example.

Basically, there are two threads that produce a value (`QueueItem`) and add it to a central queue.  Each producer will then wait between 250 milliseconds and 5 seconds before queuing the next item.

There is a single consumer thread which takes the next `QueueItem` off the queue (when it is available) and displays it...

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ProducerConsumer {

    private BlockingQueue<QueueItem> queue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProducerConsumer();
    }

    public ProducerConsumer() {
        queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

        startThread(new Consumer(), false);

        startThread(new Producer("One"), true);
        startThread(new Producer("Two"), true);
    }

    protected void startThread(Runnable runnable, boolean daemon) {

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.setDaemon(daemon);
        thread.start();

    }

    public class Consumer implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    QueueItem next = queue.take();
                    System.out.println("Picked " + next);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Producer implements Runnable {

        private final String name;

        public Producer(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep((int)(250 + (Math.random() * 4750)));
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }

                queue.offer(new QueueItem(name));

            }

        }

    }

    public class QueueItem {

        private final String name;
        private final Date date;

        public QueueItem(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            date = new Date();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "From " + name + " @ " + date;
        }

    }        
}
```

The basic idea is that you should have one or more "producer" or "generator" threads generating content into your queue(s), each one of "these" would then sleep at a random interval.

This way, you can scale the producers up or down as you need

Comment: I was really looking for code snippet of arrayed threads where there are threads that is arrayed , I already have a producer that creates delay for producing, but I want to make and thread that would sleep for random and would not create problem with the other person. it's like going to CR doing some stuffs, I want that actual situation to be in my program. Thank you by the way

Comment: MadProgrammer I think it's what they called threadpools I just don't how would I implement it on my program. where worker is actually a thread but can be reproduced as a Thread as many times as the loop goes. I think a worker threads that is being reproduces a lot of times is the solution to my code.